# SSRS Creating Mailing Labels creates two pages on 2 column page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have  a page to create labels. It prints the left column fine. But it creates two pages instead of a single page. 10 labels should be on one page 2X4in labels. Avery 5163. I have looked all around the web and most of the examples show three columns.

Comment: Please read this and edit your question to provide all required info. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The margin made the labels wider than the page size.